# how to use updatepanel with AsyncRefresh event

Tags: asp.net

I  developing an asp.net web application.In that application i am using asyncRefresh event
for continuously updating the value.If i am using updatepanel the asyncRefresh event won't get the focus.Without updatepanel evet getting the focus.I want to use asynRefresh event with updatepanel.Any one Please help for this problem.

Thanks&Regards
Lijo Thomas

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object et = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] as object;
    if (et != null)
    {
        Control c = Page.FindControl(et.ToString());
        if (c != null)
        {
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).SetFocus(GetUniqueIdSmart(c));
        }               
    }
}

protected static string GetUniqueIdSmart(Control control)
{
    string id = control.UniqueID.Replace('$', '_');
    string controlIDSuffix = "";

    RadioButtonList rbl = control as RadioButtonList;
    if (rbl != null)
    {
        controlIDSuffix = "_0";

        int t = 0;
        foreach (ListItem li in rbl.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                controlIDSuffix = "_" + t.ToString();
                break;
            }
            t++;
        }
    }
    else if (control is CheckBoxList)
    {
        controlIDSuffix = "_0";
    }

    id += controlIDSuffix;
    return id;
}
```